# Java method invocation order with chained methods

Tags: java

Given is the following Java code example:

```
builder.something()
       .somethingElse()
       .somethingMore(builder.getSomething());
```

Is it guaranteed by the Java Language Specification that `getSomething()` is invoked *after* the `somethingElse()` method or is a Java implementation allowed to reorder the execution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [JLS, Section 15.12.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.4), guarantees that the target reference is computed before arguments are evaluated.

> At run time, method invocation requires five steps. First, a target reference may be computed. Second, the argument expressions are evaluated. ...

The `somethingElse` method must be evaluated first, to compute the target reference for the `somethingMore` method.  Then `builder.getSomething()` is evaluated to supply a value for the parameter to `somethingMore`.  Then `somethingMore` can be executed.

Because of this rule, JVMs are not allowed to reorder the execution.